# How to fix the column length in a dat file and convert it to csv file

Tags: unix, awk, special-characters, fixed-length-record

My requirement is to remove the special characters and multiple consecutive spaces in unix and convert the file to the csv file . I am able to achieve above things But my problem is my output csv file column length is different from the tables column length . I need to trim the columns after removing the special characters and spaces so i cant do that in the view before bcp out the data .

I need to handle this inside the unix

Below are the commands i am using

```
bcp master..STTV_CSTDL out temp.dat -Sdev1 -Udbo -Pdbo1 -b1000 -c -t'123456789'

awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/," ")}1' temp.dat > temp2.dat

sed -e 's/  */ /g' temp2.dat > temp3.dat
```

Till this step i am able to achieve the clean data after removing the special characters but after this i need to set the column length

i have some 25 columns in which the 
column3 - 10 char(data will have max of 20 char)
column5 - 19 char(data will have max of 35 char)
column19 - 21 char(data will have max of 19 char. so extra 3 spaces should be append at last).

For this i also tried the below command but it is not working as expected

```
awk 'BEGIN {F="123456789" };
{
printf ("%-12s%-1s%-10s%-1s%-19s%-8s%-4s%-9s%-1s%-1s%-8s%-10s%-1s%-19s%-25s%-22s%-2s%-9s%-1s%-1s%-s%-s%-s%-s%-s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25)}' temp3.dat > temp4.dat
```

after using this command in certain rows the records are getting shifted to next column and file became completely overlapped. Please help me out i am struggling for 2 days for this.

Sample Input and desired Output

```
INPUT
606322089~ ~CHRISTINAITYREW~E~MARCHETTO                          ~00210816~0000~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~AD   DR    ADDRESSAD   DR    ADDRESS           U~CINCINNATI         ~OH~452060000~ ~ ~SECOSXSDS ND SAMPLE                               ~ ~ ~ ~ 

OUTPUT
606322089~ ~CHRISTINAI~E~MARCHETTO                          ~00210816~0000~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~AD   DR    ADDRESSAD   DR~CINCINNATI            ~OH~452060000~ ~ ~SECOSXSDS ND SAMPLE                             ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Note that `printf "%3s" abcdef` will *not* truncate the string to 3 chars, you have to do that yourself if necessary (use `substr()`)

Comment: @ glenn jackman i tried substring also in awk command `MFNAME=substr($2,1,10)
MLNAME=substr($4,1,19)
CSADDR=substr($14,1,25)
CSCITY=substr($15,1,19)
CSNAME=substr($20,1,50)` still it is not trimmed

Comment: @EdMorton added sample input and output file

Comment: Have you tried to use the **precision** field in the printf directives?. Read printf(3) manual pages.

Comment: Examples of use of precision field:# printf "X%.3sX\n" aaaaaaaaaaaa
XaaaX

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some examples using precision field:

```
# printf "X%-3.3sX\n" .
X.  X
# printf "X%-3.3sX\n" .........
X...X
# printf "X%-.3sX\n" .........
X...X
# printf "X%.3sX\n" .........
X...X
# printf "X%.3sX\n" .........
X...X
# printf "X%.5sX\n" .........
X.....X
# printf "X%.5sX\n" .
X.X
# printf "X%5.5sX\n" .
X    .X
# printf "X%-5.5sX\n" .
X.    X
```

Pay attention on the effects of the combination of **precision** field and **width** field when the value to print is smaller than the **width** field and **precesion** field values.